# Problems saving bitmapimage to file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on an application that has to store images from an IP camera to a file. I don't want to store the video stream. I just want to take an image every hundred or so milliseconds.

I use a specific url to get JPEG images from the IP camera which was supplied by the manufacturer. I save the image that I get from the IP camera in a BitmapImage but when I want to save the BitmapImage to a file it saves an empty .jpg file in the directory that I specify.

What I don't understand is that when I want to display the BitmapImage in an Image control then it shows the actual image, but when I want to save it, it saves an empty file.

Could anyone please advise me on how to solve this problem or maybe where it can find a solution?

I have already tried JPEGBitmapEncoder for this but no success.

Here is the code that I am currently using:

private void captureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string photosLocation, newPhotos;

```
        photosLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\IP Cam Photos";
        newPhotos = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(photosLocation);
        camLocation = photosLocation + "\\" + newPhotos;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(camLocation);
        captureStatusLabel.Content = "Photo capturing started!";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            camImage = new BitmapImage();
            camImage.BeginInit();
            camImage.UriSource = new Uri("http://172.16.4.14/image?res=full&x0=0&y0=0&x1=1600&y1=1200&quality=12&doublescan=0", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            while (camImage.IsDownloading) 
            {
                captureStatusLabel.Content = "Capture Busy";
            }
            camImage.DownloadCompleted += camImage_DownloadCompleted;
            camImage.EndInit();
            captureStatusLabel.Content = "Photo " + (i + 1) + " captured!";
        }
    }

    void camImage_DownloadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a++;
        camImgLoc = camLocation + "\\Image " + a + ".jpg";
        FileStream camFiles = new FileStream(camImgLoc, FileMode.Create);
        JpegBitmapEncoder camEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        MessageBox.Show(camImage.IsDownloading.ToString() + "\n" + camEncoder.ToString());
        camEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(camImage));
        camEncoder.Save(camFiles);
        camFiles.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some source code?

Comment: It sounds like the image has not been downloaded completely when you are saving it. You may check the BitmapImage's [IsDownloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.isdownloading.aspx) property and perhaps move the save code to a [DownloadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted.aspx) event handler.

Comment: I have added the save code to the DownloadCompleted event handler but it still is saving it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. I just need to use the correct url in the request and then it works perfectly.
`public void ReceiveImage(string imageURL)
        {
            HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageURL);
            imageRequest.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse imageResponse = (HttpWebResponse)imageRequest.GetResponse();
            using (Stream inputStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite("SonyCamera.jpg"))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead != 0);
                }
            }
        }`